# access second level subfolders in bat-File

Tags: batch-file, navigation

I already looked at this site and others for an answer, but I could not find any, so here is my simple question. I have a dvd which has several folders (named after the respective years) in it. Inside each of those there are subfolders, which then again have subfolders. So it basically looks like this:

```
2001/Projectabc/sub1
               /sub2
               /sub3
2002/Projectdef/sub1
               /sub2
```

.. and so on.

I now need a batchfile that listst me all the Projectnames without anything else and writes them inside the textfile, so that in the end I would have a fiule lookin like this:

```
Projectabc
Projectdef
```

So basically what I don't know is how do write the batch, so that it only lists the second level Foldernames.

I started like this:

`dir [Directory of dvd]:\..\  /b /a:d >> C:\folderlist.txt`, saved this as a bat file, executed it, opened my folderlist.txt and have

```
_01.2003
_01.2004
_01.2005
_01.2008
_01.2009
_01.2010
_01.2011
_01.2013
_01.2014
```

I really am stuck, since I am a newbie. Thanks very much everyone, who might help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your DVD is in drive `G:` (change the code to fit your scenario)

The following one liner will work from the command line:

```
>c:\folderlist.txt (for /d %A in (g:\*) do @for /d %B in ("%A\*") do @echo %~nxB)
```

Or using a batch file:

```
@echo off
>c:\folderlist.txt (
  for /d %%A in (g:\*) do (
    for /d %%B in ("%%A\*") do echo %%~nxB
  )
)
```

On my machine I cannot write to the system root, so I would have to change the destination folder for the output.